# Run 15.10 in a Virtualbox VM without uninstalling NVidia drivers

Tags: virtualbox, xorg

My system is dual-boot.  Sometimes I boot my Ubuntu partition natively, and sometimes as raw VMDK from my Windows 7 host.  Is it possible for me to have 3D acceleration in the VM without physically uninstalling the Nvidia drivers?

I have no xorg.conf, but for some reason, Xorg still tries to use the Nvidia GLX extension.  These lines show up in my Xorg.0.log:

```
(II) NVIDIA GLX Module  352.63  Sat Nov  7 20:52:00 PST 2015
(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

If I hide the Nvidia GLX libs, the error becomes:

```
AIGLX error: vboxvideo does not export required DRI extension
(EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
(EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: _glapi_tls_Dispatch)
(EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
(II) GLX: no usable GL providers found for screen 0
```

FWIW, my current workaround is to have a VDI with a parallel installation, which mounts the raw VMDK and symlinks to re-use my home directory.  That removes a lot of the pain from booting back and forth, although not the problem of keeping software and configurations mirrored.  Perhaps there's a configuration management solution.